# Is there an automated way to remove assets of my Rails app from the slug and instead distribute them using a CDN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

My app will eventually have lots of assets that might grow the slug size beyond 200MB. Is there a way to inform heroku not to include these assets in the slug and instead distribute them to S3 and CloudFront on every push it receives?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `asset_sync` gem.  This will do exactly what you want:

Specifically from the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem:

> Asset Sync is built to run with the new Rails Asset Pipeline feature
>   introduced in Rails 3.1. After you run bundle exec rake
>   assets:precompile your assets will be synchronised to your S3 bucket,
>   optionally deleting unused files and only uploading the files it needs
>   to.

Comment: @drop-shadow did this help?  If it did, please close this question by clicking the checkbox next to this answer. :)